# pandas-dataframe, better way then loop

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to get index distance value from an event -

event: `df['VAL'][xz] > 0) & (df['VAL'].shift(1)[xz] <= 0`

i use a loop as:

```
last = -1
df['FLD'] = -1
for xz in range(len(df)):
    if (df['VAL'][xz] > 0) & (df['VAL'].shift(1)[xz] <= 0):
        last = xz
        if (df['VAL'][xz] > 0) & (last != -1):
            df['FLD'][xz] = xz - last
```

output:

```
index ... VAL ... FLD
---------------------

0   -0.027  -1

1   -0.020  -1

2   -0.008  -1

3   -0.007  -1

4    0.012  0

5    0.031  1

6    0.023  2

7    0.016  3

8    0.009  4

9    0.005  5

10   0.001  6

11  -0.005  -1

12  -0.005  -1

13  -0.001  -1

...
```

is a way to do it without loop ?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide a relevant example dataframe. Preferably as code, for copy-paste convenience.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `apply`:

```
def get_index_distance(row):
    if (row['VAL'] > 0) and (row['VAL'].shift(1) <= 0):
        last_index = row.name
        if last_index != -1:
            return row.name - last_index
    return -1

df['FLD'] = df.apply(get_index_distance, axis=1)
```